# Mdframed and german quotation marks

Tags: mdframed, quotation

I have the following problem: I use the mdframed package for text boxes. If I use 99-66 quotation marks „...“ in my markdown editor and render a PDF with pandoc in normal text everything's fine, but in textboxes I get this:
 „...``

I use utf-8 as inputenc, so as I understood the csquotes package isn't necessary. Anyway I testet with csquotes, it makes no difference at all.

Any hints how to fix it?

Thanks Andreas

Comment: Would it be possible to show us the generated LaTeX code so we can have a look. Naively I would have thought `mdframed` should not mess with your quotation marks? (`csquotes` is also very useful if you use `utf8` `inputenc`, but it has special commands/macros you have to use instead of the normal quotation marks characters, so simply loading it without using its macros or setting up some of its auto-quote features won't change anything)

Comment: Your comment leads me to a solution: I use \newfontfamily in my code and I have to add [Mapping=tex-text] to it:
\frees[Mapping=tex-text]{FreeSans}
\newfontfamily\sfpro[Mapping=tex-text]{Source Sans Pro}

Now to works :-) Thanks

Comment: If you found an answer, please post it as an official answer in the answer section below and accept it. That way other people with a similar problem can benefit from this post.